# How can I create a border around the edge of a MATLAB figure window?

Tags: matlab, plot, border, matlab-figure

I'd like to put a border around a figure before saving my plots to .png for highlighting some plots that are most important. Is there any way to draw a rectangle outside of the axes plot region?

I'd like the border to extend around the entire plot even including the plot title and axes labels.

Comment: I'd like the border to extend around the entire plot including the title and axes labels so I don't think 'box' command will work for this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. After saving a plot to an image, you can reload it into a figure and then draw a border on top of the image.

```
img = imread('test_image.png');
fh = figure;
imshow(img,'border','tight')
hold on;
figurepos = get(gcf,'Position');
rectangle('Position',[4 4 figurepos(3)-7 figurepos(4)-7],'LineWidth',5,'EdgeColor','red')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create a variety of border types by placing the axes inside a [`uipanel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uipanel.html) and adjusting the [panel position](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.container.panel-properties.html#bt79ov_-1-Position), [edge design](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.container.panel-properties.html#bt79ov_-1_sep_shared-BorderType), [figure color](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.figure-properties.html#buiwuyk-1_sep_shared-Color), and [panel colors](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.ui.container.panel-properties.html#d119e1197796). For example, this creates a wide cyan border with a beveled-in edge that extends from the panel edge to the figure edge:

```
hFigure = figure('Color', 'c');  % Make a figure with a cyan background
hPanel = uipanel(hFigure, 'Units', 'normalized', ...
                 'Position', [0.1 0.1 0.8 0.8], ...
                 'BorderType', 'BeveledIn');  % Make a panel with beveled-in borders
hAxes = axes(hPanel, 'Color', 'none');  % Set the axes background color to none
title('Title Here');
```

[image]

And this creates a 5-pixel wide red line border tight to the edge of the figure:

```
hFigure = figure();  % Make a figure
hPanel = uipanel(hFigure, 'Units', 'normalized', ...
                 'Position', [0 0 1 1], ...
                 'BorderType', 'line', ...
                 'BorderWidth', 5, ...
                 'BackgroundColor', 'w', ...
                 'HighlightColor', 'r');  % Make a white panel with red line borders
hAxes = axes(hPanel, 'Color', 'none');  % Set the axes background color to none
title('Title Here');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Two options:

1- Set the [Clipping axes property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/clipping-in-plots-and-graphs.html) to `'off'`, and draw a rectangle outside of the axes bounds. You'll have to figure out what the right position is, using the units of the axes. This could be a little challenging to do consistently across different graphs.

2- Create a secondary axes, make it invisible, size it to occupy the full figure, and draw a rectangle in it:

```
f = figure
% One axes is invisible and contains a blue rectangle:
h = axes('parent',f,'position',[0,0,1,1],'visible','off')
set(h,'xlim',[0,1],'ylim',[0,1])
rectangle(h,'position',[0.01,0.01,0.98,0.98],'edgecolor',[0,0,0.5],'linewidth',3)
% Another axes is visible and you use as normal:
h = axes('parent',f)
plot(h,0:0.1:10,sin(0:0.1:10),'r-')
```

(I've explicitly used `f` and `h` as "parent" objects here because that typically leads to more robust code, but you can certainly leave those out, and depend on the implicitly used `gcf` and `gca` to do the right thing most of the time.)